# What does "Has been bought" stand for

Tags: grammar, cinema

What is the term "Has been bought" used for?

I saw it in the movie [Eraser (1996)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116213). Here are some lines of the transcript:

> -Captain.
>   -John, where are you?
>   -DeGuerin is the mole. He killed
>   -the others to flush out my witness.
>   -Come in.
>   -I'll protect my witness!
>   -You'll put her in danger.
>   -You'll both end up dead.
>   -DeGuerin **has been bought**.
>   -My witness knows too much.
>   -Federal agents say you are the shooter.
>   -I'll call you back.
>   -When?
>   -When I have proof.

Comment: It probably refers to "corrupted".

Comment: Probably [definition 1.4 in ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/buy): *Procure the loyalty and support of (someone) by bribery*.

Comment: No. 3 definition, to bribe, to hire http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is a 'term' as such, I'd take it at face value (as DeGuerin  is the 'bad' guy in the movie ) that he has been 'bought' / bribed / palm-oiled / became 'dirty' .